# Post image with the old Facebook sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I want to post an image from my iPhone app directly to my wall. with out using an image URL, with the actual `UIImage` or `NSData`.

On the recent FacebookSDK, I can post like:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params ..
```

and pass `NSData` of the image in `params`

but for older version `FBConect.h` can I have similar option? the one I know so far is by passing the image URL as part of the parameters dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can post image on your facebook timeline Wall like this way may be its helps you First you need to get permission to post Photo on wall in your`ViewDidLoad` Method like:-

```
NSArray* permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"user_photos", nil];
[facebook authorize:permissions];
```

now to Post image At your Button Click or your logic like:-

```
-(IBAction)ActionPostWallPhoto
{

     NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           ImageView.image, @"picture",
                                           nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];

}
```